# executing a script from anywhere

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, dos

I am writing a script for the Windows commandline. To execute the script I have to change my directory in the command line every time and then I have to execute. I need to execute the script from any directory, just by typing the script name. I am wanting to do this but in windows:

http://incube.us/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_Run_a_Script_in_Any_Language_from_Any_Directory

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the environment variables settings for windows:
my computer > right click > advanced system settings (if using vista or 7) > Advanced tab >Env. variables

just append your directory in PATH

Comment: everytime I need to find the path of the script so it will run if it is in a different location. I have thought about %~dp0 but this riquires running the file I think